# typed.js typing texts stops in the middle and not visible untill resizing the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, typed.js

I've been working with typed.js for somewhile and Im trying to print this string.

"It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like)."

my code looks like this

```
$("#level-description").typed({
                        strings: [levelContentArray[currentlySelectedLevel-1]], //Above string is stored in this array
                        typeSpeed: 30
                     });
```

It starts fine and types two lines.. after that the typer just stops. If I resize the browser window the typer types again. One thing im clear is that typed.js keeps on typing the sentences but it is not displayed. I don't know what I am doing wrong here.. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to reproduce your problem. Working example:

```js
var str = "It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).";

$("#level-description").typed({
  strings: [str],
  typeSpeed: 0
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/typed.js/1.1.4/typed.min.js"></script>

<p id="level-description"></p>
```

May I ask you to provide [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?